# Tooltip in css3 with transition effect in hover

Tags: html, css

I have made a tooltip with HTML 5 & CSS 3 with a hover effect. I have used a transition effect with height on hover. When I used `overflow: hidden;` the arrow of the tooltip disappears. What could be the problem?

I have tried `overflow: visible;` on hover and `tooltiptext::after`. But the arrow remains disappeared.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  transition: height 2s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Tooltip w/ Top Arrow</h2>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Click to go to our main course page</span>
</div>
```

The tooltip should slidedown with arrow but with overflow: hidden property the tip disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  height: 0px;
   visibility: hidden;
 overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ffff;
    color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
   transition: height 2s;
}
  .arrow{
    position:relative;
  }
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  opacity:0;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
   height: 55px;
     border: 1px solid black;
}
  .tooltip:hover .arrow::after{
    opacity:1;
  }
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Bottom Tooltip w/ Top Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <div class="arrow">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Click to go to our main course page</span>
</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

i wrapped the content in a div and applied after to this div !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of visibility property.
just remove that from both both places you've defined it and your example will work.
visibility cannot be animated. try opacity instead if you need to

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to consider the arrow inside the height of the `tooltiptext`. To do this you can create the border using the other pseudo element then add more padding-top for the arrow:

```css
body {
 text-align:center;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
  width: 100px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 10px 5px; /*Increase the padding-top*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  transition: height 2s,visibility 0s 1.5s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 7px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  z-index:-1;
}
/* to create the border */
.tooltip .tooltiptext::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px; /* we offset the top by the arrow height*/
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background:#fff;
  z-index:-1;
}
/**/
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 55px;
  transition: height 2s,visibility 0s 0s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Tooltip w/ Top Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Click to go to our main course page</span>
</div>
```